# Multiple constructor in flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to add multiple constructor in my code but it shows error. help me to solve this.

code :

```dart
class NoteModify {
  const NoteModify({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      
  String NoteID; 

  NoteModify(String x) {
    NoteID = x; 
  }
}
```

I need to use both constructor. Because I am working with 2 buttons and one button for navigate without sending data to another activity and one button for navigate with data to another activity.

[image: error log screenshot]

Comment: Can you include more detail on the error log.

Comment: check https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/constructors-in-dart/ and https://medium.com/jay-tillu/constructors-in-dart-4f972186c372

Answer (score 0):

Dart doesn't support methods/constructor overloading. But you can have multiple named constructor

Here

```
class NoteModify{
  
   String NoteID; 

   NoteModify({Key key}) {
   // main constructor
 }



   NoteModify.formId({this.NoteID}){
   //Here is the named constructor
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Jigar Fumakiya said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68780745/12066144), dart doesn't support overloading.

You need to use differently named constructors to fix the error

```
NoteModify is already declared in this scoped
```

However, you have another issue, you declared a `const` constructor and `String NoteID` is not a `final`. To declare a `const` constructor, all the fields must be `final`.

That is why you get the error

```
Error: Constructor is marked as 'const' so all fields must be final
```

If you need the `const` constructor:

```dart
class NoteModify{
   const NoteModify({Key? key}) : NoteID = null, super(key: key);

   NoteModify.formId({this.NoteID});

   final String? NoteID; 

}
```

If you need `NoteID` to be a variable instead, you'll have to remove the `const` keyword:

```dart
class NoteModify{
   NoteModify({Key? key}): super(key: key);

   NoteModify.formId({this.NoteID});

   String? NoteID; 

}
```

Comment: There was a third issue (which you corrected but didn't mention), which is that `NoteID` was declared to be non-nullable but wasn't initialized to in all constructors.